# HR line to border line

Tags: css

I had a `<hr>` line styled with a linear-gradient that I can no longer use. Instead I have to solve it via a bottom border that should be styled in the same way. I know borders can be styled using a linear-gradient as well, however, I can't get it to work.

I had the following code applied to the `<hr>`:

```css
hr.mydivider {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
}
```

Could anyone help me in translating this to a bottom border?

I would much appreciate any help!!

Many thanks
David

Comment: you need also to set size and repeat  ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image and also the plain rule

Comment: I test this code and worked well. <hr class="mydivider"/ >

Comment: @hosseinbadrnezhad but I cannot use a <hr> tag. I need to it as a border bottom style...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to apply the linear-gradient to a border. I don't see anything in the W3 CSS spec, which shows that it can be done. I don't find anything here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/. You could switch the `<hr>` tag to a `<div class="mydivider">` tag. Simply remove the `hr` before the `hr.mydivider` in your CSS snippet. Then the `.mydivider` class will be applied to the `<div class="mydivider">` tag.

Comment: @G-Cyr but how can i apply the code to a border bottom via CSS as opposed to an <hr> tag?

Comment: @Clomp if i apply it to a div then the whole div has a gradient linear background, while only the bottom should have a gradient linear border. You can see that its generally possible here: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-gradient-border/

Comment: Nice link! I figured it out by reading their site & using JSFiddle. I've posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/1unk2uo3/), which shows the bottom border as being applied to a div. It doesn't need a height. I gave the JSFiddle example a height of 40px, to show that it's only being applied to the lower border.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mydivider"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mydivider {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Comment: THIS WORKED!!!! Thank you so much Clomp! I truly appreciate this!

Comment: You're welcome! :)